# How to get association name from within an ActiveRecord instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following models: an order with a shipping address and a billing address. On initialization of each address, i'd like to automatically set a type field to determines the kind (ship, or bill).

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :ship_address, class_name: 'Address'
  belongs_to :bill_address, class_name: 'Address'
end

class Address < ApplicationRecord
  after_initialize do |address|
    #how do i know if it's a :ship_address or :bill_address?
    self.kind = "ship" 
  end
end
```

i'd like to automatically set a type field so i get the following:

```
address = Order.create_ship_address!(params)
address.kind #=> "ship"
```

I have checked Reflections but it looks like this works well for a Class but not for an instance.

Answer (score 0):

Simply merge `kind = 'ship'` in your params before creating address

```
params.merge(kind: "ship")
```

then call,

```
address = Order.create_ship_address!(params)
```

Now you will get,

```
address.kind #=> 'ship'
```

Answer (score 0):

So i eventually fixed this by leveraging Rails ActiveRecord internal syntax, which made it very quick and convenient:

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :ship_address, -> { where(kind: :ship) }, class_name: 'Address'
  belongs_to :bill_address, -> { where(kind: :bill) }, class_name: 'Address'
end
```

I decided to add a field `kind` to my Address model and i used the `Enum` functionality likes this:

```
class Address < ApplicationRecord
  enum kind: [:ship, :bill]
end
```

Overall, using an ActiveRecord association with a scope solved my problem. It makes it very convenient to use, since when you instantiate a new Address, the `kind` attribute is already set, effectively solving my problem.

```
@bill_address = Order.last.build_bill_address
@bill_address.kind #=> 'bill'
```